# Unicode characters string

Tags: c#, unicode

I have the following `String` of characters.

```
string s = "\\u0625\\u0647\\u0644";
```

When I print the above sequence, I get:

```
\u0625\u0647\u062
```

How can I get the real printable Unicode characters instead of this \uxxxx representation?

Comment: I find the question a bit vague, do you control that string? If so, just remove one of the backslashes, ie. "\u1234\u5678". If not, you should consider using regex with a callback method to parse out the number, convert it to a char, and then return that char as a string

Comment: What do you mean by "you can't control the string"? What's your scenario?

Comment: Ok I found the answer: System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape()

Comment: How do you go the otherway, ie. from unescaped string that contains the Unicode character to the \\uXXXX escaped form? 
PS: I have tried the obvious `Regex.Escape(...)` method, but it doesn't work with the following:
tomato sauce #thankyou!

Comment: @MarcAndreson please add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted, so that others will see clearly what solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asker posted this as an answer to their question:

> I have found the answer:
>
> ```
> s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(s);
> ```

Answer (score 6):

If you really don't control the string, then you need to replace those escape sequences with their values:

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})", m => ((char)Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value, 16)).ToString());
```

and hope that you don't have `\\` escapes in there too.

Comment: The correct answer that works is System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape()

Comment: I believe the MatchEvaluator should be: `m => ( (char) Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value, 16) ).ToString()`.

Comment: @MarcAndreson Make no mistake, "works" and "correct answer" are not related.

Comment: Exception thrown: Insufficient Hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Regex`:

```
String inputString = "\\u0625\\u0647\\u0644";

var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(inputString, @"\u([\dA-Fa-f]{4})"))
{
    stringBuilder.AppendFormat(@"{0}", 
                               (Char)Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value));
}

var result = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the following string "\u0001" and I wanted to get the value of it. 
I tried a lot but this is what worked for me

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToChar("\u0001")); // val = 1;
```

if you have multiple chars you can use the following technique

```
var original ="\u0001\u0002";
var s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < original.Length; i++)
{
    s += Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToChar(original[i]));
}

// s will be "12"
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest the use of `String.Normalize`. You can find everything here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/8eaxk1x2.aspx

Comment: `Normalize` does Unicode normalization, this is a *completely* separate concept.