# How to remove the unicode character in the string

Tags: c#, unicode, escaping

Say we have a string like below.

```
string s = "此检查项己被你忽略，请联系医生。\u2028内科";
```

How can I remove the unicode character like `\u2028` in the string ?

I had tried the below function. Unfortunately they all doesn't work. Please save me. Thanks.

[Unicode characters string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700800/unicode-characters-string)

[Convert a Unicode string to an escaped ASCII string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/convert-a-unicode-string-to-an-escaped-ascii-string)

[Replace unicode escape sequences in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738282/replace-unicode-escape-sequences-in-a-string)

**Updated**

Why the below code doesn't work for me ?

[image]

**Updated**
I tried to display the string in the output. It is a line separator.

[image]

Comment: hmm if you only want to remove that specific text in string then you could do `s.Replace('\'+"u2028", "");`

Comment: Are you sure that what you are seeing isn't a debugger artefact? If you were to write the string to a log/console/`Debug.WriteLine`, you'll see that the debugger visualizer includes escape codes that aren't the actual value of the string.

Comment: I want to remove all these kinds of unicode characters in my string.  not just `\u2028`.Thanks. @Agent_Orange

Comment: Really: Take a look https://pasteboard.co/HaaWlfi.png What you are seeing is a debugger artefact.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed No, the line below the regex is highlighted yellow. That's where the debugger is stopped.

Comment: @Joe.wang Oh i m sorry :v

Comment: @spender I tried `Debug.WriteLine` to display it in the output. I think it is a line separator. Thanks.

Comment: The fundamental premise of your question (removing unicode) is broken, because all strings are stored as unicode in memory. All the characters are unicode.

Comment: Unicode character 2028 (hex) is a "line separator"

Comment: The debugger does not display the string as it "really" is in memory, but a representation that could be used directly in source code. That is why you might see escape sequences like this, or extra backslashes before quotes and such.

Comment: @spender I have to remove these unicode character. Because next thing I want to do is string matching. For example. `string.index("some words")`. I think string without these unicode characters is different with the original. Thanks.

Comment: Something like `string.Concat(input.Where(c => !char.IsSeparator(c))`?

Comment: Still no lucky. @spender

Comment: Ok. (I edited the above slightly, but now it gobbles spaces too). I don't think there's a one size fits all solution here. I don't know what the separator rules are for this character set but you may find a combination of methods on `char` (such as `IsLetterOrDigit` etc) that might suit your needs in a LINQ statement.

Comment: There are two many of them(`\uxxxx`) to deal with . I can not do it one by one . Thanks.@spender

Comment: Have you tried with `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode()` or `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()`? This is their job.

Comment: `@"[^\u0000-\uFFFF]+"` is the set of UTF-16 code units not in the range of all UTF-16 code units—in other words, an empty set. Perhaps you meant `@"[\u0000-\uFFFF]+"`. (That statement must have been an experiment because it either does nothing or replaces all non-empty strings with the empty string.)

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @spender in the comments above:

> The fundamental premise of your question (removing unicode) is broken, because all strings are stored as unicode in memory. All the characters are unicode.

However, if you have a *non-escaped string* in the format `"\uXXXX"` which you'd like to replace/remove, you can use something like this regex pattern: `@"\\u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}"`

Here's a complete example:

```
string noUnicode = "此检查项己被你忽略，请联系医生。内科";

// If you hard-code the string, you MUST add an `@` before the string, otherwise,
// the "u2028" will get escaped and converted to its corresponding Unicode character.
string s = @"此检查项己被你忽略，请联系医生。\u2028内科";
string ss = Regex.Replace(s, @"\\u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}", string.Empty);

Debug.Print("s = " + s);
Debug.Print("ss = " + ss);

Debug.Print((ss == noUnicode).ToString());
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SMFAq4) to test, and here's its output:

[image: Fiddle]

Note: Since the string is hard-coded, you have to use an `@` here to prevent the sub-string `"\u2028"` from being converted to the corresponding Unicode char. On the other hand, if you get the original string from somewhere else (e.g., read from a text file), the sub-string `"\u2028"` is already represented *as is*, there should be no problem, and the above code should work just fine.

So, something like this would work exactly the same:

```
string s = File.ReadAllText(@"Path\to\a\Unicode\text\file\containing\the\string\'\u2028'");
string ss = Regex.Replace(s, @"\\u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}", string.Empty);
```

Comment: No. adding `@` before the string is different. \ will be escaped to \\

Comment: It doesn't work, I checked it: `此检查项己被你忽略，请联系医生。 内科
` still shows that Unicode.

Comment: @Joe.wang EXACTLY, otherwise it will have the actual Unicode char instead of "\u2028".

Comment: @FaizanRabbani What exactly did you try? I just updated the fiddle, please check it and let me know what doesn't work.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed if you view the string in `HTML Visualizer`, you can still see that Unicode character

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Did you check the fiddle above? Did you check the output for the line that says `Console.WriteLine(ss == noUnicode);`?

Comment: You are adding `@` sign. That's the difference.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Exactly, you either have to add an `@` *when hard-coding the string* or get the string from somewhere else (e.g., text file). FYI, [here's the VS version](https://s13.postimg.org/67h2rjebr/image.png)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yes I tried with `@` character and it works

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Sorry. I should say "unvisible unicode char".

Comment: @Joe.wang What exactly does that mean? Do you mean the string `"\u2028"` is already escaped and is represented as the corresponding Unicode char? If so, then it's no different from any other char, how do you think you can identify it?

Comment: I edited the answer several times in the last couple minutes to make things more clear. Perhaps you haven't checked the updated version. Please do.

Comment: we know all the char in the string are unicode . I think it is because `\u2028` can not display like other char in the debugger. so it just display the code point in the debugger. @AhmedAbdelhameed

Comment: so .I think more precisely saying . they are invisible unicode characters.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Thanks man, I think your answer is not right for my question. I think @spender had answer something in the comment. `string.Concat(input.Where(c => !char.IsSeparator(c))`.I can see It is right way to solution so far. I don't know if there is better solution. Let's wait and see. Thanks.

Comment: The question and answer I've been looking4.